# Going through a object with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I guess I didnt really know how to ask this question for me to find an answer.

So I have three variables that are going to make this function do what it has to

```
    function gatherDataForGeographic(ele) {
        var $this = $(ele)
        var $main_title = $this.find('.options-title'),
            $option = $this.find('.option');
        var arr = []
        var reportAreas = reportManager.getReportAreasObject();


        $option.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            var $checkbox = $this.find('.checkbox');
            var type = $this.data('type'),
                index = $this.data('index');

            if ($checkbox.hasClass('checkbox--checked')) {
                console.log(reportAreas.type)
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
        return arr;
    }
    //this will return an object that I need to index  
    var reportAreas = reportManager.getReportAreasObject();

    //this will get the a key that i need from the object 
    var type = $this.data('type');

    //this will give me the index I need to grab
    var index = $this.data('index');
```

So what I am trying to do is go through the object based on the type(or key) from the option selected by a user

The problem...
It is looking for `reportArea.type[index]` and is not recognizing it as a variable and I keep getting `undefined` because .type does not exist.

Is there a way for it to see that type is a variable and not a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic properties in JS using the bracket syntax, not the dot syntax:

```
reportAreas[type]
```

That will resolve to `reportAreas['whateverString']` and is equivalent to `reportAreas.whateverString`- `reportAreas.type` however, is a literal check for `type` property.

Comment: Oh perfect, that was easy. Thank you so much! I will accept this as the answer when time allows.

Answer (score 1):

```
reportArea[type][index]
```

JavaScript objects are just key-value pairs and the dot syntax is just syntactic sugar for the array notation.

```
object['a']
```

and

```
object.a
```

Are the same thing, basically.